# Best practice to play segments of larger video files in HTML5 video format

Tags: html, audio, video, ffmpeg, avisynth

I have to migrate a legacy project from Windows Media to HTML5 video/audio. The system should provide video/audio content to the web user meeting following criteria:

1. Playout: Segments (TcIn to TcOut) of large video/audio files should be played "on the fly" to the web user. (Cutting the source material into segments does not work because there is a high overlap rate between segments, so 3-4 times more HDD space and a lot of extra programming would be needed. Markered playout of the large source files is not an option either as there are forbidden parts of the source material which should never be available to the user).
2. Cutting: In general, users are permitted to make copies of the material. Indeed, by using the dowload function, users can download selected segments. I guess, this is not a problem: a service starts a cutting software (probably ffmpeg) that cuts the video, and the user is notified by email to download the product. (That's the way I do it now but there might be a more simple option).
3. Formats: what is the preferred video/audio format that most browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Android) support?
4. Server: If possible, I would keep Windows Server because the database behind is MS SQL Server.

(Windows Media Server and WMEncoder currently works fine for all the above, however WM is not suppored by browsers any more. That is the reason for reengineering).

I would appreciate any of your suggestions on how to rebuild this video/audio system. (What software elements to use and how).

Thank you.

-------- addition -------
Dear commenters,
Thank you for your comments. Please note that the above is one single question, the rest is just a detailed description of the issue/conditions, as recommended by stackoverflow.com. I guess, the answer is also very simple, I try to write it myself:

1. You should keep the large video/audio files in **xxx** **format** **because**...
2. You create a playlist file like **this example...** for each of the the segments.
3. You install the **xxx streaming software** component on the web/media server to playout the segments.
4. You can address and play the segments from the client side web browser like **this**:...
5. For asynchronous cutting, yes, I recommend ffmpeg, try **these** profile settings.

Just a few parts in bold are missing. Thanks to anyone who can fill them.

Comment: As it's a very specialized thing, thus no guarantee to obtain a [complete] answer here, I'd recommend reading various articles on html5 streaming like [this one on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Setting_up_adaptive_streaming_media_sources).

Comment: Hi there, you might well be better off asking some of these in one of the other stack areas such as Programmers or Server Fault. SO is really for specific problems with code or code tools rather than generalised questions. At the very least it would be a good idea to ask your questions separately, a user may know how to answer one of the points without knowing anything about the others which makes it hard to formulate and choose a single answer.

Comment: You should break this down into sub questions. One post one question. Based on what I read, you seem to not have a full grasp of  how modern segmented HTTP streaming works. You would be well served by reading up on HLS, DASH, MSE EME, and truly understand how they work at a server and client level. The alternative it to outsource to a company who already does this. (there is nothing here that a company like brightcove doesn't do 1000 times a day)

Comment: Dear @szatmary, I added some info to my question. Regards.